# Spring Transaction Isolation Level

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, transactions

Most of us might be using Spring and Hibernate for data access.
I am trying to understand few of the internals of Spring Transaction Manager.

According to Spring API, it supports different Isolation Level - [doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Isolation.html)
But I couldn't find clear cut information on which occasions these are really helpful to gain performance improvements.

I am aware that `readOnly` parameter from `Spring Transaction` can help us to use different TxManagers to read-only data and can leverage good performance. But it `locks` the table to get the data to avoid dirty-reads/non-committed reads - [doc](http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/spring-transaction-isolation-tutorial).

Assume, in few occasions, we might want to blindly insert the records into a table and retrieve the information without locking the table, a case where we never update the table data, we just insert and read [append-only]. Can we use better Isolation to gain any performance?

1. As you see from one of the reference links, do we really require to implement/write our own CustomJPADiaelect?
2. What's the better Isolation for my requirement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Read-only` allows certain optimizations like disabling dirty checking and you should totally use it when you don't plan on changing an entity.

Each [isolation level](http://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-transaction-isolation-levels-in-enterprise-java/) defines how much locking a database has to impose for ensuring the data anomaly prevention.

Most database use [MVCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control) (Oracle, PostgreSQL, MySQL) so **readers don't lock writers** and **writers don't lock readers**. Only **writers lock writers** as you can see in [the following example](http://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-database-locking-and-the-lost-update-phenomena/).

`REPEATABLE_READ` doesn't have to hold a *lock* to prevent a concurrent transaction from modifying your current transaction loaded rows. The MVCC engine allows other transactions to read the committed state of a row, even if your current transaction has changed it but hasn't yet committed (MVCC uses the undo logs to recover the previous version of a `pending changed` row).

In your use case you should use `READ_COMMITTED` as it scales better than other more strict isolation levels and you should use [optimistic locking](http://vladmihalcea.com/preventing-lost-updates-in-long-conversations/) for preventing lost updates in long conversations.

---

### Update

Setting `@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)` to a Spring bean has a different behaviour, depending on the current transaction type:

- For `RESOURCE_LOCAL` transactions, the `JpaTransactionManager` can apply the specific isolation level for the current running transaction.
- For JTA resources, the transaction-scoped isolation level doesn't propagate to the underlying database connection, as this is the default JTA transaction manager behavior. You could override this, following the example of the `WebLogicJtaTransactionManager`.

Comment: I have gone through your blog too before this post. But do we really require to implement our own JPADialect to implement this?

Comment: You shouldn't implement the JPADialect, why did you assume that?

Comment: one of the reference links points to that. By default it's not supported :-/ I found it hard to believe though

Comment: Send me the link, I don;t understand what you are referring to.

Comment: please refer this http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/spring-change-transaction-isolation-level-example

in fact, custom implementation is shown there

Comment: For JPA, the isolation level is properly taken from @Transaction. If you use JTA, you need some workarounds, as the JTA standard doesn't support it.

Comment: for SO users, can you please explain the detailed answer about using different Isolation Levels and sample use cases. It will be helpful for many users.

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer. I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: @VladMihalcea, can you please check my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32114750/spring-transaction-by-connecting-to-multiple-databases

Answer (score 2):

Actually `readOnly=true`doesn’t cause any lock contention to the database table, because simply no locking is required - the database is able to revert back to previous versions of the records ignoring all new changes.

With readOnly as true, you will have the flush mode as `FlushMode.NEVER` in the current Hibernate Session preventing the session from committing the transaction. In addition, `setReadOnly(true)` will be called on the JDBC Connection, which is also a hint to the underlying database not to commit changes.

So `readOnly=true` is exactly what you are looking for (e.g. `SERIALIZED` isolation level).

[Here](http://www.skill-guru.com/blog/2010/12/19/transactionalreadonlytrue-in-spring/) is a good explanation.

Comment: I might agree with `readOnly` part. What about `writes`? Can we use any specific isolation level in such scenarios?